# varibale wc product for alert message

Tags: php, html, css

I want to write for WooCommerce product features with .. alert and I need help to complete the code

If the user selects a variable from the available product and one of the variables selected by the user is null, I want to show a warning to the user.

`

```
<?php
// PHP program to pop an alert
// message box on the screen
  
// Display the alert box 
echo '<script>alert("Welcome to Geeks for Geeks")</script>';
  
?>
```

`

`
this is my code

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean, maybe this can help you

```js
function Check(){
        var prod = document.getElementById('product1').value
        if(prod <= 0 || prod == ""){
            alert("Failed");
            } else {
            alert("Success")    
            }
        }
```

```html
Product 1 
  <input type="number" id="product1" value="" size="5">
  <button type="button" onClick="Check()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, suppose
We have a product that has an XL size and it has 2 colors, red and blue
We have 2 pieces of blue color in stock
But there are 0 pieces of red in stock

We want to show a message to the user if the user chooses the red size XL, that the stock of this variable in the warehouse is 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).